# iPhone SDK errors in Xcode

Tags: iphone, web-services, asihttprequest

how can I fix these errors? :(
comments beside the errors

thanks!

**AuthenticationViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableData *dataWebService;
}
```

**AuthenticationViewController.m**

```
#import "AuthenticationViewController.h"

@implementation AuthenticationViewController
```

//Missing @end

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

//expected ';' after method prototype

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *yourPostString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" write here your SOAP Message or JSON input (depend on your webservice)"];

    dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoursite/webService"]] retain];

    NSString *postLength =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [yourPostString length]];

    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[yourPostString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [myConnection start];    

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [dataWebService setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [dataWebService appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);

    [responseString release];

    [dataWebService release];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Eror during connection: %@", [error description]);

}
```

//Missing @end

**error log**

> CompileC
>   build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/Objects-normal/i386/AuthenticationViewController.o
>   "iPhone Sample/AuthenticationViewController.m" normal i386 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler cd
>   /Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2 setenv LANG
>   en_US.US-ASCII setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe
>   -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings
>   -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
>   -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2
>   -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch
>   -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30103 -iquote
>   "/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/ASIHTTPRequest
>   iPhone-generated-files.hmap"
>   "-I/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/ASIHTTPRequest
>   iPhone-own-target-headers.hmap"
>   "-I/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/ASIHTTPRequest
>   iPhone-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote
>   "/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/ASIHTTPRequest
>   iPhone-project-headers.hmap"
>   -F/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -I/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
>   -I/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -I/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/DerivedSources
>   -include
>   /var/folders/Cs/CsqSKcbMEOC12Z96tZhqZ++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/iPhone_Prefix-gdcjyckfdobukjghijdsfunokuto/iPhone_Prefix.pch
>   -c "/Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/iPhone
>   Sample/AuthenticationViewController.m" -o
>   /Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/build/iPhone.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhone.build/Objects-normal/i386/AuthenticationViewController.o
>
> /Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/iPhone
>   Sample/AuthenticationViewController.m:3:17: error: missing @end 
>   @implementation AuthenticationViewController
>                    ^
>   /Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/iPhone
>   Sample/AuthenticationViewController.m:5:20: error: expected ';' after
>   method prototype
>    - (void)viewDidLoad
>                       ^
>                       ;
>   /Users/Desktop/ASI/pokeb-asi-http-request-57f7ff2/iPhone
>   Sample/AuthenticationViewController.m:56:5: error: missing @end  @end
>        ^ 3 errors generated.

Comment: Nicely written question for a newbie on stackoverflow. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of a class is done within the blocks

```
@implementation classname

@end
```

You have forgotten to add @end at the end in your .m file.

Its same for the `@interface` declarations too.

Comment: Thanks Praveen S, I added the @end at the bottom of the .m file and it still says the same errors :(

Comment: How about your header? Add it in the header file too. Can you post the error log completely? Its simple error.

Comment: Sure! one sec, i'll add it in.

Comment: Add @end at the end of your header file.

Comment: error: use of undeclared identifier 'dataWebService' AND error: no super class declared in @interface for 'AuthenticationViewController'

Comment: Ok you delete your code and add your header file afresh and your .m file to it. Just plain code. Dont add comments and don't miss any line out.

Comment: Hi Praveen S, yes I did, i followed your instructions and it works! Thank you!!!! Sorry I forgot about this question.